# Annotate type as typeof subclass of base class

Tags: typescript, oop, typing

Given a `Parent` class with children `ChildA` `ChildB`

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract foo()
}
class ChildA extends Parent {
    foo() { }
    bar() { }
}
class ChildB extends Parent {
    foo() { }
    baz() { }
}
```

How can I strictly type a function's parameter as being any class *(the class itself, not an instance)* that conforms to the type `Parent`, but is not itself `Parent`

```
fn(Parent) // Should fail, is supertype rather than subtype
fn(new ChildA()) // should fail, is instance of subtype rather than class itself
fn(new ChildB()) // should fail, is instance of subtype rather than class itself
fn(ChildA) // Should succeed
fn(ChildB) // Should succeed
```

Comment: Don't use empty classes as examples! Since TypeScript is **structurally typed**, empty classes are basically the same thing as `{}`.

Comment: That being said, I think you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkEELN). It only works because `Parent` is abstract. If `Parent` is not abstract, then it'll take a little more work.

Comment: [This version](https://tsplay.dev/WvkkMw) works even if `Parent` is not abstract. If these work for you, let me know which one I should expand into an answer.

Comment: @pink fantastic, thanks. In my case the base class is abstract, but it'd probably be useful to mention the non-abstract case too.

Comment: @pink also, feel free to edit or suggest an edit to the title or body if you think there's better phrasing/snippets I could have used for SEO and theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `fn` as the following, using a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures):

```
function fn(ctor: new (...args: any[]) => Parent) {}
```

This describes a constructor that creates something which extends `Parent` (structurally, in the type system). Funnily enough, this is very close to the [example in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) on abstract construct signatures.

Passing in `Parent` will fail since `Parent` has an abstract constructor:

```
fn(Parent);
// ~~~~~~ Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4IAOOBiAvAgAwIC+AUCmhgMIAWAlsgCYBBBLgAeEAnwzY8hBCWAIa9Zq3QIuvPgCFhYiVIqySIRXUZMmAMwCu+eNwD2+BJfwAKeA6gAuBPlwA7ghuAHRhOADmYL7A+ACeANoAugCUigB8WIYQaUTMVu7SlGkA9CUIAMqcDtb8LsC8ADR+DojcGGDWpLhQEHHdCDAQnD0Iw7EInSB93QVu-kEa-AJuKaXlYNW1fPVNCO37+JCxsLgIDpaT1tP9Z0MjUGOcE6oY3BBguMiWcwvqPPwtKt1pMtnVLA1kM0DtwjhATmcLlcbgN7qNxs5XvsPl8fq43EtBCCqjU6p1YKdcHw5oStMSwTtyZTqUwgA)

---

It may also help to mention a method that will work even if the Parent class is not abstract. You would need to check if the given class is the Parent or not first. Thankfully, this is possible, since types are inferred before being instantiated:

```
function fn<Ctor extends new (...args: any[]) => Parent>(ctor: typeof Parent extends Ctor ? never : Ctor) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3tADo1GAvNAAzQC+AUKJDAMIAWAliACYCC0SAHmqqzHjJ0WaGGjEyVGlGiMWrAEJde-QfhHYARhNIVKlAGYBXFMDRMA9imiGUAHjppLCFXxQDoKJAHdoACgA6YMQAcwgALjEUAE8AbQBdAEoJAD44DTRU-3MXKLQYnCRLQwzhDB53TycXaAB+LyQANyRXKJqEFMwqIxR-IQIUgHoh6ABlBktjNlswFgAaL0sMJhgIYyKEAqLoBDA0BlboA7Abda1tpF7-bz95NnZ-JOHRiEnp1lmF6FWflAg0KdgEhoCVoOdLrt9odXCcbDIYEw0BAkCBDNdbnJmGxFE8XuD3jNDHMQItfkx-oCzCCwRDCiC9gcjnDoAifsjUei7P57hx8RMpjN1sBgUhWNdeYp+YTPsLReLKEA)